# Report Viewer - Paging Issue

Tags: c#, asp.net, google-chrome, ssrs-2008, report-viewer2010

I'm new to reporting services and having trouble getting a report to render correctly on my ASPX page. **I'm using MS Report viewer 10 using with asp.net 4.0.**

other than Chrome, in all browsers paging is working fine. but while using chrome its continuous showing loading.hence no more response from report.

[image]

[image]

Any Suggestion Appreciated !!

Comment: any body have any idea on this ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could you please refer below link, it may help you?

http://blog.lavablast.com/post/2011/06/28/Gotcha-Reporting-Services-Viewer-bugs-on-Google-Chrome.aspx

Report viewer doesn't support chrome:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms251673%28v=vs.100%29.aspx

Comment: thanks manoj... but i know abt this but is there anyworkaround for the same